# How Do I Get Multiple JButtons To Work?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, calculator

I'm trying to make a simple adding calculator using Java. I try to get my buttons to work but they won't. This is the code that recognizes what buttons are pushed and when to calculate. It is very small because I am only trying small parts to see if it works:

```
static void something(ActionEvent e) {
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int answer = 0;
    //equals, plus, and one are all the names of JButtons
    while(e.getSource()!=equals&&e.getSource()!=plus) {
        if(e.getSource==one) {
            //The math is making it so as you type in more numbers, more numbers appear
            num1 = num1*10+1;
            //sayNum means say a number
            sayNum(num1);
        }
        if(e.getSource()==2) {
            num1 = num1*10+2;
            say(num1);
        }
    }
}
```

It never seems to enter my main void. Here is my entire code, but I took out that small piece of code above:

```
package Calculator;
import javax.swing.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public abstract class CalculatorClass implements ActionListener {

    static JButton one = new JButton("1");
    static JButton two = new JButton("2");
    static JButton three = new JButton("3");
    static JButton four = new JButton("4");
    static JButton five = new JButton("5");
    static JButton six = new JButton("6");
    static JButton seven = new JButton("7");
    static JButton eight = new JButton("8");
    static JButton nine = new JButton("9");
    static JButton zero = new JButton("0");
    static JButton plus = new JButton("+");
    static JButton equals = new JButton("=");
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    static JTextArea field = new JTextArea();
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        equals.setSize(225, 75);
        plus.setSize(75, 225);

        field.setSize(250, 75);
        seven.setBounds(0, 75, 50, 50);
        eight.setBounds(75, 75, 50, 50);
        nine.setBounds(150, 75, 50, 50);
        four.setBounds(0, 150, 50, 50);
        five.setBounds(75, 150, 50, 50);
        six.setBounds(150, 150, 50, 50);
        one.setBounds(0, 225, 50, 50);
        two.setBounds(75, 225, 50, 50);
        three.setBounds(150, 225, 50, 50);
        zero.setBounds(0, 300, 50, 50);
        plus.setBounds(225, 75, 75, 225);
        equals.setBounds(75, 300, 225, 75);
        equals.setVisible(true);

        buttonSetup(one);
        buttonSetup(two);
        buttonSetup(three);
        buttonSetup(four);
        buttonSetup(five);
        buttonSetup(six);
        buttonSetup(seven);
        buttonSetup(eight);
        buttonSetup(nine);
        buttonSetup(zero);

        frame.setSize(306, 403);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setTitle("Calculator");
        frame.add(one);
        frame.add(two);
        frame.add(three);
        frame.add(four);
        frame.add(five);
        frame.add(six);
        frame.add(seven);
        frame.add(eight);
        frame.add(nine);
        frame.add(zero);
        frame.add(plus);
        frame.add(equals);
        frame.add(field);

        one.setVisible(true);
        two.setVisible(true);
        field.setVisible(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    say("Ready!");
    sayNum(56);
}
public void setup() {
    one.addActionListener(this);
    two.addActionListener(this);
    three.addActionListener(this);
    four.addActionListener(this);
    five.addActionListener(this);
    six.addActionListener(this);
    seven.addActionListener(this);
    eight.addActionListener(this);
    nine.addActionListener(this);
    zero.addActionListener(this);
    equals.addActionListener(this);
    plus.addActionListener(this);
    say("Setup is done.");
}
static void say(String s) {
    String msg = s;
    field.append(msg + "\n");
}
static void sayNum(int i) {
    int msg = i;
    field.append(""+ msg + "\n");
}
static void buttonSetup(JButton b) {
    b.setSize(75, 75);
    b.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

I would put the .addActionListener(this); into the main(String args[]) but it says, "Cannot use this in a static context." Then I take out the static in void main, the errors go away, but when I run it, it says there is no main type. I then put the static back, but then the error pops up again. If you need me to put my question down in a more clear form, just ask. Keep in mind I'm not even 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite a bit wrong with your code. First I suggest you review the code I've attached so you can see a simple example of how to make a form with a button on it, and how to handle the click events on the button. Ive demonstrated how to do it with defined action listeners and with anonymous ones.

Note that I create a form object inside of my main method, then I set that form up inside of its constructor. This is where the majority of your problems are coming from because you try to accomplish all of this inside of your main method, and thus from a static context.

I edited this post to include two buttons handled differently on the form.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MainF extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainF f = new MainF();
    f.setVisible(true);

}


public MainF() {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 300);
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JButton someButton = new JButton("Some Text");
    JButton someOtherButton = new JButton("Some Other Text");
    //Add an anonymous one
    someButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I was clicked and handled anonymously!");
        } });
    //add a defined one to our other button
    someOtherButton.addActionListener(new buttonListener());
    this.add(someButton);
    this.add(someOtherButton);
}


private class buttonListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I was clicked and handled by buttonListener!");
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write listeners for your buttons.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

EDIT:

This may be helpful as well.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mH1TltI61yU

Comment: His main form is the action listener, I think the method something() is the actionPerformed implementation.

Comment: I did, in void setup. Except when I typed in setup(); in the main(String args[]) void, an error came up saying that I had to change setup() to a static void, I did but it didn't work.